# 500 Internal Server Error when pass data in $.ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am receiving a 500 internal server error when making an ajax call.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txtSearch").change(function(){
        var search = $("#txtSearch").val();
        var str = 'search=' + search;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "searchProcess.php",
            data: str,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                if (data["type"] == "1") {                     
                    alert('Please Enter Value To Search');

                }else if (data['type'] == "2") {
                        alert('No Such of This Event In Database');


                }else if (data['type'] == "3")  {
                    $('#gallery').hide().html(data['data']).fadeIn('5s');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**searchProcess.php**

```
if (!isset($_POST["search"])) {
    print json_encode(['type'=>'1']);

}else{

    $seValue = "%{$_POST['search']}%";

    $querySel     = "SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE galleryTitle LIKE :title OR date LIKE :dat";
    $stmtquerySel = $conn->prepare($querySel);
    $stmtquerySel->bindParam('title',$seValue);
    $stmtquerySel->bindParam('dat',$seValue);
    $stmtquerySel->execute();

    if ($stmtquerySel->rowCount() == 0) {

        print json_encode(['type'=>'2']);

    }else{

   $galleryGrid = "";
        while ($rowQuerySel = $stmtquerySel->fetch()) {

            $id    = $rowQuerySel['galleryId'];
            $image = $rowQuerySel['image'];
            $title = $rowQuerySel['galleryTitle'];
            $date  = $rowQuerySel['date'];

            $galleryGrid .= "<div class='col-lg-4 col-sm-6'>
                            <div class=''>
                                <a href='gallerydetails.php?id=$id'>

                                 <img src='img/$image' width='100%'>

                                 <div>Event Name:$title</div>
                                <div>Date :$date</div>
                                 </br></br>


                                </a>
                                 </div>      

                        </div> 


            ";
        }
        $galleryGrid .="<div class='col-md-11 text-center'>
              <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' onClick=location.href='gallery.php'>Back</button>
            </div>";

        print json_encode(['type'=>'3', 'data'=>$galleryGrid]);
    }
}
```

when I try it on `localhost` it run , but when upload to `server` then will get 500 internal error

Comment: You might have an error at `searchProcess.php` file you need to debug that first

Comment: If you get a 500 internal server error you mostly likely have an error in  `searchProcess.php`. Have you tried debugging `searchProcess.php` to see where your error occurs?

Comment: Post code of `searchProcess.php` file too !!

Comment: There's something wrong with php code.

Comment: Looks like a PHP error. either your PHP url is incorrect, or most likely there is syntax or logical error in that PHP file.

Comment: but when i run it at localhost , it okay..no error ..only when upload to ftp server

Comment: is there proper reference for connection object `$conn` in your searchProcess.php file?

Comment: ya ...i already include database file

Comment: Why don't you check server logs ? It will give you reason for 500 ISE.

Comment: check the permission of searchprocess.php on server

Comment: On the server, did u check where the request is going. if part or the else part?

Comment: permission i already set it to 777

Comment: Can you remove all the codes in searchProcess.php and put only this: print json_encode(['type'=>'1']); and tell the status?

Comment: Try passing a complete URL to your file

Comment: I think you should try this `print json_encode(array('type'=>'3', 'data'=>$galleryGrid));` instead of `print json_encode(['type'=>'3', 'data'=>$galleryGrid]);`

Comment: finally work !!! thxx harry bomrah

Comment: @ChHong no problem. I will then paste the answer just for future views to this question. Maybe can help someone else too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
 print json_encode(array('type'=>'3', 'data'=>$galleryGrid));
```

instead of

```
print json_encode(['type'=>'3', 'data'=>$galleryGrid]);
```